# Not a group by function at a cumulative query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm making a cumulative query, which shows the evolution of clients in my database. To get these query, I use the year and the week of year they joined in the client database.

I have following query to search for relevant data:

```
SELECT DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR, SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ID)) OVER ( ORDER BY DD.CAL_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS "Number of account statements"
FROM CLIENT_DATABASE FAB
JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
GROUP BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
```

But when I compile this query, I get following error:

> Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>
> SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: 979

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try just `SUM(DISTINCT FAB.ID)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ID)`  I dont think you can do both together. And what are you trying to do by the way?

Comment: Without a group by, the combination of sum and count works. I need to have the sum of all the numbers of data, so that's why I use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are grouping by `DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR`, you can't use `DD.CAL_DATE` in the `order by` clause of your cumulative sum function.

It's hard for me to say exactly what you are trying to do without fully understanding your data.  But, logically, it does seem like you should be able to simply use `DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR` in the `order by` clause instead of `DD.CAL_DATE`, and still get the results the way you are expecting.

So something like this:

```
SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ID)) OVER ( ORDER BY D.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR ...
```